# PHP - Convert JSON to Plist?

Tags: php, json, plist

How would one use PHP (and whatever necessary libraries) to convert JSON data to Plist data?

Comment: `json_decode($json);`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer it into an array first. After that, do whatever you want with that

```
json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would decode the data and then encode it using [CFPropertyList](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList)

Simply:

```
$plist = new CFPropertyList();    
$td = new CFTypeDetector();  
$guessedStructure = $td->toCFType( json_decode($json) );
$plist->add( $guessedStructure );
$xml = $plist->toXML();
```

Comment: CFPropertyList is a bit heavy... Looking for a simple lightweight solution. Maybe I have to invent that myself...

Comment: It is pretty heavy, but the OP asked how to convert JSON to Plist format. Why the above answer is accepted, I have no idea. I have personally written a recursive algorithm for generating Property List XML from an array or object structure. Unfortunately the code is not mine to publish, but you can write your own in a few hours.

Comment: I went with JSON as is. I guess it's a bit more lightweight when it comes to transfer times (negligable maybe), and there are some easy-to-find JSON libraries for Obj-C out there...

Comment: I agree - use JSON over XML unless you absolutely need a PList. There are one or two use-cases, but not many.